# How can I recover my documents from iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud

My username with Apple is a very old one. Old enough that until iOS 5 it wasn't associated with an email address. It was just a simple username. With the latest upgrade I was required to transfer to a name associated with my preferred email address. This seems to have gone well with the exception that iCloud can no longer locate my Pages and Numbers documents. Apple seems stumped and the system will no longer let me log in with the old username. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you use iCloud before without a correct form of AppleID? you wouldn't be able to login or connect devices.

Comment: When you say Apple is stumped, do you mean Apple the company or Apple the computer/phone?

Comment: Since we need more info to answer this and the asker hasn't given the info, I'm closing this.